# WPF count the number of frames in a video C#

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I would like to count to total number frames in a video after the mediaelement opens. The MediaElement.RenderedFramesPerSecondProperty does not work, when I do this I get an error saying; "System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement does not contain definition for RenderedFramesPerSecondProperty". 
I am using MediaElement in WPF to play the video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge there is no way I suppose.

Try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024169/capture-each-wpf-mediaelement-frame) link to dig in more.

I checked out more and found this solution -

Microsoft provides a free diagnostic tool that will tell you the frame rate at which WPF is updating the screen? I guess if you're not convinced you're getting the framerate you're asking for, then perhaps you might not trust it, but I've found it to be a reliable tool. It's called Perforator, and it's part of the WPF Performance Suite, which you can get by following the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa969767

Hope this helps you.

Comment: after hours and days of research, there isn't indeed a way to do it. Anyway; instead of using Media element i used opencv and created a C# wrapper class. Thanks!